# Does Enterprise COBOL support Free Format source code

Tags: cobol, cobol-zos

Does IBM Enterprise COBOL 6.X support free format and variable format source code? I have searched for a statement confirming this but could not find any. I also checked the compiler options and found no option/flag for this feature that was introduced in 2002 and 2014 standards.

I don't have access to a mainframe or I would have tested my self of course.

If you have knowledge in this subject kindly let me know. It would be super cool if you could provide a link.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe Enterprise COBOL for z/OS support free format source code.

There was an [RFE submitted back in 2013](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=32108) which was declined in 2020 since "based on our current plans and priorities, it is not likely that this could be implemented in the next 12 months".

But they said they might reassess the request when they work towards alignment to the standards.

Comment: Utterly incredible. I implemented it in a day or so in 1981.