# gnucobol "unexpected Identifier, expecting DIVISION"

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

I write simple program:

```
000100 IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
000200 PROGRAM-ID. dnd.
000300 AUTHOR. Ishayahu Lastov.
000400 DATE-WRITTEN. 15/05/2023
000500 ENVIRONMENT DIVISON.
000600 DATA DIVISION.
000700 01 Username PIC X(20)
000800 01 CharactersCount 10
000900 PROCEDURE DIVISION.
001000 DISPLAY "LaSil/IT D&D 5e"
001100 DISPLAY "What is your name?"
001200 ACCEPT Username
001300 DISPLAY "How many characters are in group?"
001400 ACCEPT CharactersCount
001500 DISPLAY "Hello " Username ". You want " CharactersCount "characters..."
001600 STOP RUN.
```

(I tried write it in free format, but got the same error, so I used fixed format (as I understand at the moment). And as I understand from [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68801807/1440299) free format could be not used in enterprise, so I'm not sure that is worse to start with it)

**cobc -fixed -vvv main.cob**

```
cobc (GnuCOBOL) 3.1.2.0
Built     May 05 2023 16:23:39  Packaged  Dec 23 2020 12:04:58 UTC
C version "FreeBSD Clang 13.0.0 (git@github.com:llvm/llvm-project.git llvmorg-13.0.0-0-gd7b669b3a303)"
loading standard configuration file 'default.conf'
command line:   cobc -fixed -vvv main.cob
preprocessing:  main.cob -> /tmp/cob77473_0.cob
main.cob:16: error: continuation character expected
return status:  1
parsing:        /tmp/cob77473_0.cob (main.cob)
main.cob:5: error: syntax error, unexpected Identifier, expecting DIVISION
return status:  1
```

As I understand from an error, compilator want to see "DIVISION" after "000100 ", but as I see from all examples first line is fine

Comment: Changing the format won't help the fact your missing the WORKING-STORAGE SECTION  and that your picture clauses are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is:

> main.cob:5: error: syntax error, unexpected Identifier, expecting DIVISION

checking your line 5:

```
000500 ENVIRONMENT DIVISON.
```

as the compiler points out `DIVISON` is a possible user-defined COBOL word, an identifier, but it expects the reserved word `DIVISION`.

After fixing that you'll get more errors to fix (missing storage section, periods in the data definitions, likely `PIC 99` instead of `10`...), but in general the compiler messages should point those out to you as it did here.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a period after the date written date.